# Powershell Get-ADUser and variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to write a Powershell script that will allow me to query the `samaccountname` and other fields from a list of e-mail addresses. (reverse lookup)

My email.csv file has a users header, followed by the list of e-mail addresses.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$users = Get-Content .\email.csv
$users | ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(emailaddress=$users)" -Properties samaccountname | Select-Object -Property samaccountname
} | Export-Csv -Path .\emailexport.csv
```

Comment: Replace `$users` in the ldapfilter string with `$_`

Answer (score 1):

you will need to change `$_.emailaddress` depending on your column title in your csv file. also, samaccountname is returned by default for get-aduser, so you can leave that part off.

```
$users = Get-Content .\email.csv
$users | ForEach-Object {
    $email = $_.emailaddress
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(emailaddress=$email)" -Properties emailaddress |
    Select-Object -Property samaccountname, emailaddress
} | Export-Csv -Path .\emailexport.csv
```